# Disabled format-detection for iPhone/iPad webapp not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, web-applications

I have a webapp that displays many long numbers recognized as telephone numbers on iPhone / iPad. I used the meta tag mentioned in apple's reference to disable it:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```

But this does not work if i load or reload the page normally. When I am reloading a part of the page with ajax, it suddenly works and the numbers are normal text. But when i reload the page, the numbers are links again. This happens also if the ajax loaded content is exactly the same that was at the place before the ajax request.

If i view the page in the browser (not as webapp) it works right from the beginning.

Do you know why this is happening, and how i can fix it?
Is there any other way to force numbers to not being links.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Am experiencing the same problem - it's very annoying!

Answer (score 4):

Try and add this to YourProjectAppDelegate.m

```
// ...

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    theWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll ^ UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;    
    return [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
}

// ...
```

Did the trick for me..

Comment: I put this in my WebViewController.m file and it worked great too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to go through the entire process of bookmarking the app to the Home Screen to force the cache to update.

You also have the correct code for [**format-detection** according to Apple's guide to Apple-specific meta tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) except they do not have the meta tag as self closing with trailing slash:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: I bookmarked and now the tag is working as expected when I open the site via the Home Screen shortcut (`format-detection` off). But when I open Safari and visit the URL directly it still doesn't work. I thought maybe it was still cached in Safari but I tried on a phone that has never visited the site and it has the same problem -- `format-detection` still seems to be on. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem where an embedded web page worked fine in a browser, but the problem occurred when embedded in an app. This was due to the meta tag being over written by settings in the app itself, see http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber.

May help?

Comment: Its not an embedded webpage in native application. It's a webapp = customized webpage = pure html + JS + css.